# Conbine arrays to organized payload data

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to unique values from this for loop and organized them 
Payload:

```
$name = ['Mazda','Mazda','Lexus', 'Lexus'];
$count = [1,1,1,1];
$gp =[54,35,23,46];
```

I Have a payload that I am trying to organized the data into arrays based on the "unique" name so I can total the results and eventually pass it to a PDF. The column that I am trying to create is a total Column.

example.

```
NAME  | C | GP |
------|---|----| 
Mazda | 2 | 89 |
Lexus | 2 | 69 |
```

what is the best way to go about this?  I thought about doing array_unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my approach

```
// Data
$name = ['Mazda','Mazda','Lexus', 'Lexus'];
$count = [1,1,1,1];
$gp =[54,35,23,46];

// declare result array
$result = [];
// do Looping
for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
    $result[ $name[$i] ] = [
                        "C" => ($result[ $name[$i] ]['C'] ?? 0) + $count[$i],
                        "GP" => ($result[ $name[$i] ]['GP'] ?? 0) + $gp[$i]
                        ];
}
print_r($result);
```

Demo : https://3v4l.org/U3nQ0